# Complicated MySQL query with multiple AND OR WHERE conditions

Tags: mysql

I've got a table for helping choose products.

I would like to have a query where I got back every record where:

```
category_id = 'M10' and band_id = '010'
OR
category_id = 'M10' and band_id = '020'

AND

category_id = 'M50' and band_id = '010'
OR
category_id = 'M50' and band_id = '020'
```

My query:

```
SELECT 
product.entry_id AS entry_id, 
helpme.item_id AS product_id 
FROM inbound_help_me_choose helpme 
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles product ON (product.product_id = helpme.item_id) 
WHERE 
helpme.submarket_id = 'NZ' 
AND 
(
(helpme.category_id = 'M10' AND helpme.band_id = '010') 
OR 
(helpme.category_id = 'M10' AND helpme.band_id = '020')
)
```

works fine on the first category, but as soon I'm adding new WHERE conditions are failing:

```
SELECT 
product.entry_id AS entry_id, 
helpme.item_id AS product_id 
FROM inbound_help_me_choose helpme 
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles product ON (product.product_id = helpme.item_id) 
WHERE 
helpme.submarket_id = 'NZ' 
AND 
(
(helpme.category_id = 'M10' AND helpme.band_id = '010') 
OR 
(helpme.category_id = 'M10' AND helpme.band_id = '020')
)
AND
(
(helpme.category_id = 'M50' AND helpme.band_id = '010')
OR 
(helpme.category_id = 'M50' AND helpme.band_id = '020')
OR 
(helpme.category_id = 'M50' AND helpme.band_id = '030')
)
```

It seems OK for me, so I completely lost why it's not working.

Comment: Even if everyone knows ANDs get precedance before ORs in conditional logic, I always recommend using parenthesis for clarity especially once you start getting past two or three conditions in your clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need this

```
SELECT 
product.entry_id AS entry_id, 
helpme.item_id AS product_id 
FROM inbound_help_me_choose helpme 
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles product ON (product.product_id = helpme.item_id) 
WHERE 
helpme.submarket_id = 'NZ' 
AND 
(
   (helpme.category_id = 'M10' AND helpme.band_id IN ('010','020')) OR 
   (helpme.category_id = 'M50' AND helpme.band_id IN ('010','020','030'))
)
```

Comment: @rs. Your query  fixes his logic (assuming what's shown in the conditional logic at the start of the question is really what's wanted/expected)

Comment: @rs. You've actually got a slight error with mismatched closing parathesis. Making a minor edit to your answer...

Comment: Your solution doing exactly what I wanted, however finally figured that I might should have a union.

Answer (score 1):

Changing a little bit what you need:

```
category_id = 'M10' and band_id = '010' OR category_id = 'M10' and band_id = '020'
AND
category_id = 'M50' and band_id = '010' OR category_id = 'M50' and band_id = '020'
```

is the same as:

```
category_id = 'M10' and (band_id = '010' OR band_id = '020')
AND
category_id = 'M50' and (band_id = '010' OR band_id = '020')
```

is the same as:

```
category_id = 'M10' and category_id = 'M50'
AND
(band_id = '010' OR band_id = '020') and (band_id = '010' OR band_id = '020')
```

`category_id` cannot be both `M10` and `M50` so you're not going to get any results...

Answer (score 1):

The conditions in your where clause inside the 2nd example query you show in your question, the one hitting with problems in its where clause, can never evaluate to true...

The first where clause alone from the first example requires that the category_id to be equal to M10.

Then in the second example the where clause gets another group of statements added to it with an 'and'.  The issue is that this where clause want only records with a category_id of M50

Regardless of any other issues with logic, i can be fairly certain you won't find a record having a category_id of both M10 and M50 at the same time.

Another user, @rs. posted a query with a modifided where clause in that meets the conditional logic rules as specified at the start or your question.

Answer (score 0):

The `x AND y` operator means that both the `x` and `y` conditions it applies to need to be satisfied at the same time. You just need to use the `OR` operator instead.